# prolog dynamic predicates difference between /1 and /2

Tags: dynamic, prolog, predicate

I am a beginner in the Prolog language and I am in a situation where dynamic/1 is being used. In my code there is a line, for example that goes like this:

`:- dynamic actual_position/1, at/2, holding/1, talked/1, examined/1.`

I want to understand why actual_position has a /1 as compared to at which has a /2.

Thank you!

Comment: The number ofter the `/` specifies the number of parameters.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The number after the slash (`/`) is the *arity* of the predicate: it is the number of parameters it takes. So `member/2` means a `member` predicate or functor with two parameters.

The arity is important since, just like in Java for example, one can *overload* predicate names: one can define multiple predicates with the same *name* but a different arity. For example [**`append/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/2) concatenates a *list of lists* to a single list, whereas [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) appends two lists together in a single list.

Comment: And we have the DCG rules: `foo//2` taking two hidden parameters for the threaded list. There is, however, no fixed syntax for (arithmetic) functions: `foo/(2)` would be nice. Nor for SWI-Prolog dict-associated predicates (which I like to name dot-calls. `.foo/2` would be nice.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: We cannot define arithmetic functions in ISO-Prolog and so no arity-overloading is possible. And arithmetic functions are mostly unary or binary. If we are using one we know which is which.